# Rhino - Convert Parameter Map to Native JS object

Tags: request, rhino, parameters

What's the "right" way to convert the parameters from request into a native JS object?

It seems that no matter what I do, I end up with a java object.

Answer (score 0):

PrimitiveWrapFactory will do what I'm looking for, but the easiest way is to just call:

String(javaObj), since I always want them as strings.